# Type error: Too few arguments to function App\User::removeMood(), 0 passed in and exactly 1 expected

Tags: laravel

Here is my code where Error occurs.

```
public function index(MoodOfTheDay $request)
{
        $authUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
        $datetime = new DateTime();
        $currentDatetime = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $subcategory_ids = $request->get('subcategory_ids');
        $subcategories = Subcategory::whereIn('id', $subcategory_ids)->get();

        $userFriends = $authUser->friendslist()->get();
        $userFriendIds = $authUser->friendslist()->pluck('id')->toArray();

        $authUser->removeMood();
        foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
            $authUser->addMood($subcategory);
        }
 }
```

Comment: your removeMood method expects and ID you don't pass it

Comment: I can not pass any ID here beacause i do not need it

Comment: can you show your removeMood method here?

Comment: public function removeMood()
    {
        return $this->userMoods()->detach();
    }

Comment: You would like remove all users using detaching, because your code say this but i am sure that in userMoods you passing ID

Answer (score 0):

Your `removeMood()` like this:

```
public function removeMood($userId) { 

   return $this->userMoods($userId)->detach(); 
}

$authUser->removeMood($authUser->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your `route` in `web.php` file,
check if your route has parameter remove it

it is possible your route is like this :

```
Route::post/get('/url/{parameter}' , 'controller@method')->name('route_name');
```

change this to:

```
Route::post/get('/url' , 'Controller@method')->name('route_name');
```